# Conceptual Help needed with Database Queries

Tags: mongodb

So, I don't have a specific issue here other than a general lack of knowledge, and I am hoping that the big brains on here can give me a nudge in the right direction or maybe refer me to an online resource that could help...here is the general problem I am trying to solve.

I have a mongo database that holds a handful of collections where I store data retrieved from some software that we use for our day to day operations.  We are grabbing this data from the API and storing it in Mongo to build up a historical source of data (the API is limited in the timeframe of data that can be retrieved.)

The window for the historical data from the API is 7 days.

The data in question has a unique id for each item we pull from the API, so this allows us to grab a record, store it, and modify it as required if it changes over time.  This has been working just fine for our needs, until we started to notice a few discrepencies between the data we stored in Mongo, and what we would get out of our software when we ran "reports."  After digging into it, turns out there are a few edge cases where a record would be deleted from the software, but if we already grabbed that record through the API, then it would remain in our Mongo Database.

I'm looking for any advice on how to handle this situation.  Ideally I suppose we would like to remove these deleted records from our mongoDB inorder to match what is in the software...but I'm having trouble dreaming up the process to make this happen.  Apparently this is one of many gaping holes in my entirely self-taught knowledge of this stuff.

Thanks for any assistance.